# What's the downside of dying?

Tags: absolver

I've died a few times already. If another player character is near me, they can help me up. Otherwise, I can wait 60 seconds (which I haven't done; I'm impatient), or I can respawn instantly.

What is the downside of any of this? What do I lose by dying?

Comment: I'm glad this wasn't ISP.se ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a couple posts in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/absolver/comments/6wqkvd/death_penalty/?ref=search_posts), you lose any experience gained in the fight where you died. That is, you don't earn experience unless you beat the opponent.

> I just completed the tower, but it's doesn't seem there is apart from if you have learned moves during the fight and you die, you lose the moves experience.

---

> yeah there are no penaltys. the exp you gain towards learning moves in that fight is lost. you only get that exp once you beat them, but if i beat 1 person and die a second later i don't lose anything.